# Android obfuscation

Tags: android, kotlin

I have Android Studio 4.1.2
I want to test an obfuscation in my project. In gradle i have

```
 buildTypes {
    ...

    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
        )
        debuggable false
    }
}
```

I want to make sure my classes are obfuscated. I suppose when i call to

```
myObj.javaClass.simpleName
```

I will get something like

**a.f.c...**

But i getting not obfuscated class name

Comment: How are you viewing the "not obfuscated class name"?

Comment: Log.d("...","simpleName name = ${this.javaClass.simpleName}")

Comment: Are you sure you're running the `debug` flavor? You can check in the Build Variants tab on the left. Make sure it's debug and not release. Although you probably want to enable minification for the release build, not debug anyway. What you've done is convert your debug build into something like a release build, when you could have just switched to testing your release build in the Build Variant tab.

Comment: Actually, debug and release have the same rules.

Comment: Can you share your proguard file? Also, try to create an APK and then inspect it using Android Studio. Build -> Analyze APK. Click on the classes<x>.dex files until you see your root package folder. See if the classes there are obfuscated or not.

Comment: I have default proguard file. i did it, it is not obfuscated